# Fit a table to page width

Tags: tables, booktabs

I am new to Latex and making tables using booktab.

I made a table with hierarchy in the x-axis such that I have 3 columns and each column further has 3 sub-columns.
But, the table fails to fit within the width of the page as shown below

[image]

I tried many solutions such as tabu, adjustbox, resize box and tabular*, but they do not seem to fix the problem or I do not know the proper syntax.

The code that I used is attached below with resize box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} 
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}}
\newcommand{\nm}[1]{\textnormal{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [h!]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {%
\begin{tabular}{LCCCCCCCCC}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{N N}    &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{MM}    &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{DW}    \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-10}

&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column One} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column two} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column One+col2} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column One} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column Two} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column One+col2} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column One} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column two} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column One+col2}     \\
\midrule

experiment1 & a  & b & c & d \\
experiment2 & p & q & r & s \\ 

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Description of the table}\label{beta}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

After using the resize I get the following

[image]

Can anyone help me this? 
Thank You so much in advance.

Comment: A giraffe doesn't fit to a guinea pig cave. If you may enlarge the `\textwidth`, your (much too wide) table will fit. You can also re-create your table to be narrower.

Comment: Add `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` to see if your table with the `\resizebox` is actually fitting in the margins.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: what do you mean by enlarge the \textwidth

Comment: @jon: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: @user2948166 If you, not, e.g., a journal, decide, how wide is a column, you can write, say, `\textwidth17cm`, providing more space for your table.

Comment: Add the line as suggested to your preamble and recompile your posted example file.  You do not need to make any other changes.

Comment: @jon: it does fit the margin. What can be done to sort of enlarge the table?

Comment: We need to see a more realistic example with some representative data so that we know what goes in the columns. One fix (from the given table) would be to eliminate the word `column` from the column headings. Alternatively you could rotate the table so that you have larger width to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example of the solution without using more advanced methods, as rotating. It summarizes my suggestions from comments. Heavy line shows the width of text and separates from an original (not scaled) example. There are some changes in text, but probably without loss of understanding it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\oddsidemargin-1cm
\textwidth17cm
\def\COMP#1{\begin{tabular}{c}#1\end{tabular}}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} 
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}}
\newcommand{\nm}[1]{\textnormal{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [h!]
\centering
%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {%
\begin{tabular}{LCCCCCCCCC}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{N N}    &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{MM}    &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{DW}    \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-10}

&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\COMP{col.\\ One}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\COMP{col.\\ two} }&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\COMP{col.\\ One\\+col2}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\COMP{col.\\ One}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\COMP{col.\\ Two}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\COMP{col.\\ One\\+col2}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\COMP{col.\\ One}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\COMP{col.\\ two}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\COMP{col.\\ One\\+col2}}     \\
\midrule

ex1 & a  & b & c & d \\
ex2 & p & q & r & s \\ 

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}%
%}
\caption{Description of the table}\label{beta}
\end{table}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1mm}

\begin{table} [h!]
\centering
%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {%
\begin{tabular}{LCCCCCCCCC}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{N N}    &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{MM}    &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{DW}    \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-10}

&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column One} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column two} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column One+col2} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column One} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column Two} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column One+col2} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column One} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column two} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{column One+col2}     \\
\midrule

experiment1 & a  & b & c & d \\
experiment2 & p & q & r & s \\ 

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}%
%}
\caption{Description of the table}\label{beta}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
        \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}           
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\nm}[1]{\textnormal{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [h!]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} {%
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{1cm}}cc cc cc cc c}
\toprule

\multicolumn{3}{c}{N N}    &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{MM}    &
\multicolumn{3}{c}{DW}    \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){1-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-6}
\cmidrule(lr){7-9}


\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{column One} &
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{column two} &
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{column One+col2} &
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{column One} &
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{column Two} &
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{column One+col2} &
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{column One} &
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{column two} &
\multicolumn{1}{C{1.5cm}}{column One+col2}     \\
\midrule

\multicolumn{9}{l}{Experiment 1}\\ \cmidrule{1-2}
 a  & b & c & d \\
\multicolumn{9}{l}{Experiment 2} \\ \cmidrule{1-2}
  p & q & r & s \\ 

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Description of the table}\label{beta}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```